# Series of documents displayed with hide/show icons jQuery asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I've got a page with a repeater and a bunch of documents that should be hidden to start and then shown with a plus sign next to each.

My question is - do I have to assign unique ID to each document DIV to make it be able to toggle hidden and shown?

What's the most code-efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaamU/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="repeater">
      <div class="document">
        <div class="title">Document 1</div>
          <div class="button"><a href="#">+</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="document">
        <div class="title">Document 2</div>
        <div class="button"><a href="#">+</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="document">
        <div class="title">Document 3</div>
        <div class="button"><a href="#">+</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#repeater .document
{
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.document .title
{
    float:left;
}
.document .button
{
    float:right;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".title").hide();
    $(".button a").click(function(event){
        $(this).parents(".document").children(".title").toggle();
        event.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

Here is a Fork with the sliding version:

http://jsfiddle.net/W5QkY/1/

Comment: The only issue with this is when I click the + sign, the page scrolls back to the top.

Comment: updated my post, check the forked version. For your problem, make sure you add event.preventDefault

Comment: Okay. For the sliding fork, is there a way to have the toggled element start out hidden instead of having to slide it up when the method starts?

Answer (score 0):

no you dont have to assign them all a different Id. There are many ways to select multiple dom elements with one selector expression

you have a few options

1) you can assign them all the same class and then do `$('.className').show()/.hide()`

2) you can select them by a css selector related to the page's layout i.e `$('#mainContent img').hide()` will hide all images inside of a container (prob a div) with id mainContent

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign an ID, you can use their position in the document to identify the correct element.

For example, you have something like this:

```
<div id="documents">
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

You can use jquery like so to trigger individual elements:

```
$('#documents > div').eq(0).show();
```

Where the number passed to the eq() method will return the div at that index.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily avoid unique id:s on the html tags by using jQuery's [traversing capabilities](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/):

```
<div class="frame">
    [Document title] <a href="#">+</a>
    <div>[document contents, links or whatever go here]</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery magic:

```
$(function() {
    $('.frame a').click(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        if ($t.html()=='+')
        {
            $t.html('-').next('div').show();
        } else {
            $t.html('+').next('div').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You could obviously switch the `.show()`/`.hide()` calls to some animation of your choice.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo of mine. The line instantiating `$t` should have said `var $t = $(this);` - it has now been corrected.